# How to convert IEnumerable<table> to XML from Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate

All the tutorials that I see online when converting a database table to XML always involves a Data Context. However, I'm using Fluent Nhibernate mappings and therefore I don't want to do this.

Is there a way to say convert an IEnumerable to XML document instead? Or are there any other ways to get data from an Nhibernate mapped database to XML?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEnumerable<> -> Xml

1. **Linq to XML** - You can use this to build up `XElements` pretty easily from enumerables
2. **XmlSerializer** - Will serialize POCO into XML, you can wrap something to make it serialize your IEnumerable easily